# Join tables in pandas read_sql_query() - multi index problem

Tags: oracle, pandas, dataframe, join, indexing

I would like to create a pandas DataFrame using `pandas.read_sql_query()` by joining two tables. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
connection = ...
query = 'SELECT T0.*, T1.* FROM %s T0 LEFT JOIN %s T1 ON T0.NUMPERSO = T1.NUMPERSO' % (TABLE, TABLE_VARS)
raw_train_data = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection, index_col='numperso')
```

The above code creates the df `raw_train_data` but then `raw_train_data.index` returns:

```
Float64Index([[35477725.0, nan], [56756339.0, nan], [16596475.0, nan],
          [15921969.0, nan], [21866760.0, nan], [24199683.0, nan],
          [17290497.0, nan], [12785913.0, nan], [37230860.0, nan],
          [19049184.0, nan],
          ...
          [11332158.0, nan], [19624233.0, nan], [18763121.0, nan],
          [27757040.0, nan], [14169924.0, nan], [15978910.0, nan],
          [39321116.0, nan], [27472225.0, nan], [33970568.0, nan],
          [14526836.0, nan]],
         dtype='float64', name='numperso', length=289907)
```

I think the problem is that the `index_col='numperso'` exists in both tables, but putting `index_col='t0.numperso'` gives an error and I want to use ony one 'numperso' as index.

Is there a way to specify to use only one column as index when importing the tables?

**EDIT**:
I understand that the problem is that the column 'NUMPERSO' belongs to both tables. In general columns with the same name in both tables are not dropped in the `pd.read_sql_query()` step. What I did was to not specify the index, drop duplicated columns (with same name, such as 'NUMPERSO') and set the index manually:

```
raw_train_data = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
raw_train_data = raw_train_data.loc[:,~raw_train_data.columns.duplicated()]
train_data.set_index('numperso', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on what the sql query is doing, but you could just fix up your index in pandas. Try the following:

```
idx = pd.DataFrame(raw_train_data.index.values.tolist(), columns=["rtd_idx", "nan"]).set_index(
    "rtd_idx"
).index
```

I'm hoping this will give you a new index and then you can just set your dataframe.index = idx

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is similar to what I did (see EDIT). But I'm curious to know if it's possible to do it directly when importing the table created by the join statement.